# How to pass specific order pk to the bootstrap modal in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

Is there a way to pass the pk of specific let's say order pk to bootstrap model? I have tried using jquery but template tag `{% url 'accept' pk=orderPK %}` is causing the issue.

I have tried giving it directly or with template tag but seems not working.

```
$(document).on("click", "#accept_button", function () {
    let orderID = $(this).data('id');
    {#url = "{"+"%"+" url 'accept' pk = " + orderID + " %"+"}";#}
    url = "{% url 'accept' pk =" + orderID +" %}"; #with template tag
    {#url = "accept/"+orderID#}         #directly
    $(".modal-body .form").attr('action', url );
```

**Error:**

> ```
> TemplateSyntaxError at /dashboard/warehouse/response/
> Could not parse the remainder: '=" + orderID +"' from '=" + orderID +"'
> ```

**EDIT:**

After making some updates

```
url = "{% url 'accept' pk=orderID %}".replace(/orderID/, orderID.toString())
    $(".modal-body .form").attr('action',url);
```

the error changed:

> ```
> NoReverseMatch at /dashboard/warehouse/response/
> Reverse for 'accept' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['dashboard/warehouse/response/accept/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
> ```

Comment: Do you have multiple orders on one page?

Comment: Yes, i do have multiple orders.

Comment: and I assume that the issue is that when response page is requested pk is empty in template url because I am now getting this Reverse for 'accept' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dashboard/warehouse/response/accept/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is caused by this line:

```
url = "{% url 'accept' pk =" + orderID +" %}"
```

It's an invalid syntax, hence Django gives you the error.

---

One important thing to understand here is that templates are compiled at the server, and then sent to the client. Once they're out of the server, Django can't do anything with them.

So, this won't work:

```
let orderID = $(this).data('id');

url = "{% url 'accept' pk =" + orderID +" %}"
```

Here you're trying to use JS to replace the `orderID` with the id of the object. Since templates are compiled on the server, your JS code will not run. Instead Django will try to compile the url with what you've given.

And if you're thinking of re-using the `{% url %}` tag in your JS code, that won't work either, because the template is out of the server. And django can't run on your client's browser.

---

Solution will be not to use the django's template tags in your JS code:

```
let orderID = $(this).data('id');

url = '/accept/' + orderID + '/';
```

Now, I know it is bad practice to hard-code your URLs like that. So, another solution will be to set a `data-url` attribute on every order.

```
<button data-id="{{ order.id }}" data-url="{{ order.get_absolute_url }}">
```

And then read the url of the order from this data attribute in your JS code.